# Wrong response from the webhook: 400 Bad Request

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot, bad-request, php-telegram-bot

I'm recently tried to use webhook to get update from telegram. my program work correctly whit getUpdates().
but when i set webhook i got

> "Wrong response from the webhook: 400 Bad Request"

error when try to check status of webhook by getWebhookInfo method.

here is my code:
`$telegram->commandsHandler(true)`
when is used below code in getUpdates mod every thing was fine.
`$telegram->commandsHandler(false)`

And is should say i use https and my ssl is ok.

This is answer of getWebhookInfo to me.

```
{
  "ok": true,
  "result": {
    "url": "https://telbit.ir/api/bot/<token>",
    "has_custom_certificate": false,
    "pending_update_count": 13,
    "last_error_date": 1476344420,
    "last_error_message": "Wrong response from the webhook: 400 Bad Request"
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you server working correctly? Is the answer from server always 200 OK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer

every things was ok. the error happens because of my framework.